# Identify this component on wireless receiver

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, charging

I try to assemble a wireless power receiver by my self from the following [diagram](http://aitendo3.sakura.ne.jp/aitendo_data/product_img/ic/power/XKT-510/XKT-510.pdf):

[image]

I'm trying to match with the one I bought, but I'm not able to identify black component indicated on the picture. Maybe optional...
We can see **OM** on it, with my beginner's arrows :-), do anyone know what is that?
And by the way is those IC ([T3168](https://www.adrirobot.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/T3138.pdf)) need to be programmed in order the circuit to work? I guess no.

Comment: Can you tell from the PCB tracks if the mystery component is in series or in parallel with some other components?

Comment: It appears to be in parallel with C2 so my guess would be it's a zener diode to limit the voltage under no-load conditions.

Comment: Where did the schematic come from? You need to attribute the author (an SE rule).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, after using a magnifying glass and doing an electrical test, I updated the image.
KevinWhite you are probably right, in my research I saw a few zener diodes but on different diagrams.
The source of the diagram is on the link provided, see page 4.
http://aitendo3.sakura.ne.jp/aitendo_data/product_img/ic/power/XKT-510/XKT-510.pdf

Comment: I wanted to ask if that's a diode which one to use? But look like I found it https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005077966815.html (OW not OM, even do not mean nothing probably).

Comment: @Unicorn The label on the diode from aliexpress is OM not OW.

Comment: Yes you're right my friend I must have been upside down in front of a mirror.